# Convert an IntEnum field to an integer in Avro4s

Tags: scala, avro

I have a case class in Scala that I am serializing to Avro using Avro4s,
and I want to convert an enum field to an integer representation in the Avro schema. Currently, the case class looks like this:

```scala
@AvroName("MyCaseClass")
case class MyCaseClass(detectedDeliveryType: DeliveryType, ...)

object DeliveryType extends IntEnum[DeliveryType] {

  case object Unknown extends DeliveryType(0)

  case object Desktop extends DeliveryType(1)

  case object MobileWeb extends DeliveryType(2)

  case object MobileApp extends DeliveryType(3)

  case object CTV extends DeliveryType(4)

  override val values: IndexedSeq[DeliveryType] = findValues
}
```

And the corresponding Avro schema generated by Avro4s looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "detectedDeliveryType",
  "type": {
    "type": "enum",
    "name": "DeliveryType",
    "namespace": "mypackage.enums",
    "symbols": [
      "CTV",
      "Desktop",
      "MobileApp",
      "MobileWeb",
      "Unknown"
    ]
  }
}
```

Instead, I want the Avro schema to represent detectedDeliveryType as an integer, like this:

```
{
  "name": "detectedDeliveryType",
  "type": "int"
}
```

How can I achieve this using Avro4s or any other library? Thank you!